# What's the simplest way to persistently mount a file to an application hosted in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a docker image which I want to run in kubernetes. A cluster already exists and I can `kubectl` it.

The docker image will be static, but it needs a data file. In my docker-compose running locally it would be given as

```
services:
  mysvc:
    image: my-image
    volumes:
      - /home/me/data.dat:/data.dat
```

I want to upload `/home/me/data.dat` to the kubernetes cluster/pod, where it will be mounted to `/data.dat` in the container.

Later, while the application is running, I want to re-upload this file, so it will be replaced in the running container.

If the container restarts for any reason, I want the most-recently uploaded version of `data.dat` to be mounted.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a thought experiment, I didn't try it in the real world, but it is how I would have attempted the problem:

Create a [persistent volume + persistent volume claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) with access mode set to ReadOnlyMany/ReadWriteMany, mounting it in your pod and then use [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) to upload the file to the mounted path. I **assume** this would upload the file to the persistent volume, making it accessible to every pod that mounted the volume. If the container restarts, it should re-mount the persistent volume with the latest uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question:

If file size is under 1MB you can store it as a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

> A ConfigMap is not designed to hold large chunks of data. The data stored in a ConfigMap cannot exceed 1 MiB. If you need to store settings that are larger than this limit, you may want to consider mounting a volume or use a separate database or file service.

If file size is above 1MB:

- How many nodes do you have?

  - Single node: You can put it inside the host and mount with [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)/[local](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local)
  - More than one node:

    - Do you have a node affinity for your pod (in other words, is your pod going to run always on the same node?) : You can use hostPath/local ^see above
    - No affinity (pod can be assigned to any worker node): Use a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) such as NFS and mount it to your workload.